# 動的にＩＤ付与した要素を、関数側でも認識させたい。

Tags: javascript, jquery

## 質問：

動的にＩＤ付与した要素名が、関数側で認識できていない原因、対策をご教示頂けますでしょうか？

## 達成したいことのイメージ：

以下のコーディングでは、ＩＤ付与した要素の入力内容に問題があった場合、画面に対し
①エラーメッセージを出力
②その要素の背景を変える
ことを達成しようとしています。

上記①②は双方エラー処理用の関数で達成しようとしていて
背景を変更したい要素名について引数で渡しているつもりですが、関数側でうまく捉えられいないようです。
問題の要素の背景色が変わってくれません。

尚、画面が開かれた際からＩＤが設定された要素を試しに引数に与えると
エラー処理用の関数は　無事動作＝当該要素の背景色を変えることができます。

ブラウザ(IE)の開発ツール=DOM Explorerで、動的に追加したID名が問題のINPUT要素に見受けられない。しかし関数を呼び出す側で、試しにID指定で当該要素の値をメッセージボックスに表そうとすると、無事表示することができます。

毎回初歩的に思われる問い合わせを掲載してしまい、申し訳ありません。
何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

-html-

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cd" style="width:45px;"></td>
        <td><label name="name"></label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="amount" style="width:45px;"></td>
        <td><label name="unitp"></label></td>
        <td><label name="totalp"></label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

-JavaScript(jquery-3.2.1.min.js)-

```
$("input[name=cd]").on("blur",function() {
    var label = $(this).parent().parent().find("label");

    $(this).attr("id","99");        // ←【ＩＤ付番号】
    alert($("#99").val());          // ←【内容を表示できる】

    $.ajax({
        url: "cdinfoget.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            maker_no: maker_val
        }
    })
    .done(function(data){
        if (data.length <= 0) {
            label.eq(0).html("");
            label.eq(1).html("");
            label.eq(2).html("");               downtotalCalc();
            errhandler($("#99"), true, "err#005");  // ←【ＩＤ付番した要素も引数に与え、エラー処理の関数呼出し】
            $("#99").removeAttr("id");
            return false;
        }

    ....省略
    
});


//****エラー処理用の関数****
function errhandler ($obj, onoff, errno) {

    var errmsg = "[" + errno + "]" + "\n\n";

    switch(errno){
        case "err#005" :
            errmsg = errmsg + "品名コードの指定が誤っています！";
            break;
        case "err#014" :
            errmsg = errmsg + "単価の参照に失敗しました！";
            break;
        case "err#015" :
            errmsg = errmsg + "日付の指定が誤っています（休日？）！";
            break;
    }


    //第２引数＝true  ⇒ エラー    /メッセージと背景色サーモンに。
    //第２引数＝false ⇒ エラー解除/背景色は戻す。。
    if (onoff) {
        $obj.css("background-color","#FA8072");
        alert(errmsg)
    } else {
        $obj.css("background-color","#EEFFFF");
    }
}
```

Comment: 変数labelが初期化されていません。（過去の質問を確認しなくても良い様に、対象となる部分のｈｔｍｌを質問に含めるた方が良いかと）

Comment: jQuery の `attr`は[仕様変更があった](https://ginpen.com/2011/05/20/jquery-1-6-1/)(らしい)のでjQueryのバージョンを付記したほうがいいと思います。

Comment: 数字のみのＩＤは使用可能かもしれませんが、ＸＨＴＭＬなどではおそらく問題になるかと思いますので、英文字＋数字の形式に変えたほうがいいかと思います。

Comment: yyz様　BLUEPIXY様　ご見解ありがとうございました。当方がつくづく初心者であること、既にお気づきのことと思いますがIitmon様のご指摘どおりでお恥ずかしい限りです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

よく分かりませんが、わざわざidを付与する必要があるのでしょうか？
与えられたプログラムだけを見ると、 `$(this)` を変数に一度格納して使えばidを付与する必要がないように思えました。

```
$("input[name=cd]").on("blur",function() {
  var $input = $(this);
  $.ajax(~~~).done(function(data){
    if (data.lenght <= 0) {
      handleError($input);
    }
  });
});

function handleError($obj) {
  $obj.css("background-color", "#FA8072");
}
```

Comment: litmon様　ご支援をありがとうございました。本当に仰られるとおりです。Ajaxの.doneの中で$(this)で、当該の要素を捉えることができなかったことをきっかけにIDの付与をしていました。（Ajaxの.doneの中で$(this)で当該要素を捉えられない要因をしっかり認識できていない為に、皆様にご迷惑をおかけしてしまいました、今から調べてみます。動的だからかAjaxが故なのか．．．）

Comment: `.done()` の中、というか、 `function()` の中でthisを使用するとthisの向き先はfunctionになりますね。「javascript this スコープ」などで調べてみるといいのではないでしょうか？